# Could not cast value of type Kanna.libxmlHTMLNode to 'NSString

Tags: swift

I am trying to scrape some data from a website, and since there is no API, I am trying to use ALAMOFIRE + KANNA

I can print my results in the console, but as soon as I try to convert in String to use it in my app it says:

**Could not cast value of type 'Kanna.libxmlHTMLNode' (0x10887d210) to 'NSString' (0x108efc0d0).**

Why couldn't I cast the data in String using as! String

my code

```
var competitions:[String] = []


    // Grabs the HTML 
func scrapeData() -> Void {
    Alamofire.request("MYWEBSITE.com").responseString { response in
        print("\(response.result.isSuccess)")
        if let html = response.result.value {
            self.parseHTML(html: html)
        }
    }
}

func parseHTML(html: String) -> Void {
    if let doc =  try? Kanna.HTML(html: html, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {

        do {
            // Search for nodes by XPATH selector
            for competition in doc.xpath("""
 //*[@id="page_teams_1_block_teams_index_club_teams_2"]/ul
 """) {
                let competitionName = competition.at_xpath("li/div/a")
                print(competitionName?.content ?? "N/A")

                competitions.append(competition as! String)
```

Comment: You can't use `as! String` because `competition` isn't a `String` or an `NSString`.

Comment: Don't you want to append `competitionName` to your array? Why are you trying to append `competition` and ignore the code used to get the name?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: You got a HTML node (object) which cannot be converted to string. Nodes have tags, attributes, content etc. You have to specify what kind of string information you need.

Comment: Sure, i have to append `competitionName`, but even if i use  `competitions.append(competitionName as! String) ` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`competition` is a `libxmlHTMLNode`, not a `String`. You can't simply force-cast one type of object to another, unrelated type.

Most likely you want to append `competitionName`, not `competition` to your string array. But you need to convert it to a `String` using its `text` property:

```
competitions.append(competitionName?.text ?? "N/A")
```